# How to load google maps api asynchronously in Angular2

Tags: google-maps, angular

Usually in a plain javascript site, I can use the following script to reference google maps api and set the `callback` function with `initMap`.

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

What I observed is the `initMap` function in the plain javascript site is under the window scope, and it can be referenced in the script parameter settings - `?callback=initMap`, but once I write a component in angular2 with a component method called `initMap`, the `initMap` will be under the scope of my component. Then the async loading script I set up in the index will not be able to catch my component `initMap` method.

#### Specifically, I 'd like to know how to achieve the same thing in `Angular2`?

> PS: I know there is an `angular2-google-maps` component available in `alpha` via `npm`, but it currently is shipped with limited capability, so I 'd like to know how to load it in an easier way without using another component so I can just use google maps api to implement my project.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I see you don't want another component, but polymer has components that work well with google apis.  I have angular2 code that uses the polymer youtube data api. I had help getting it setup. Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bqqm9dy126sqfAMI8mFa?p=info) that got me started. I think the hardpart is getting setup for that callback, I'm sure you can do it without polymer.  The example shows the tricky part an angular service is used to hook everything up.

```html
    const url = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=__onGoogleLoaded'

    export class GoogleAPI {
      loadAPI: Promise<any>
      constructor(){
        this.loadAPI = new Promise((resolve) => {
          window['__onGoogleLoaded'] = (ev) => {
            console.log('gapi loaded')
            resolve(window.gapi);
          }
          this.loadScript()
        });
        
      }
      
      doSomethingGoogley(){
        return this.loadAPI.then((gapi) => {
          console.log(gapi);
        });
      }
      
      loadScript(){
        console.log('loading..')
        let node = document.createElement('script');
        node.src = url;
        node.type = 'text/javascript';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
        
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. It is quite self explanatory. Thanks!

Comment: Work properly on gmaps async load. Thank you!

Comment: I've just tried the code but VS says :Property 'gapi' doesn not exist on type 'Window'.

Comment: I get that as well (it's a typescript thing), but it still works. I haven't figured what to do to remove the error.

Comment: you can use window['gapi'] instead of window.gapi

Comment: With Typescript, If you declare the window object above your class, the error message should go away: `declare var window: any;`

Answer (score 9):

I came across this while trying to develop a progressive web app, i.e. where there was a possibility of not being online. There was an error in the code examples: `onload` in the google maps script should be `callback`. So my modification of user2467174 led to

**map-loader.service.ts**

```
const url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxx&callback=__onGoogleLoaded';

@Injectable()
export class GoogleMapsLoader {
    private static promise;

    public static load() {
        // First time 'load' is called?
        if (!GoogleMapsLoader.promise) {

            // Make promise to load
            GoogleMapsLoader.promise = new Promise( resolve => {

                // Set callback for when google maps is loaded.
                window['__onGoogleLoaded'] = (ev) => {
                    resolve('google maps api loaded');
                };

                let node = document.createElement('script');
                node.src = url;
                node.type = 'text/javascript';
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
            });
        }

        // Always return promise. When 'load' is called many times, the promise is already resolved.
        return GoogleMapsLoader.promise;
    }
}
```

And then I have a **component** with

```
import { GoogleMapsLoader } from './map/map-loader.service';
constructor() {

    GoogleMapsLoader.load()
    .then(res => {
        console.log('GoogleMapsLoader.load.then', res);
        this.mapReady = true;
    })
```

And a **template**

```
<app-map *ngIf='mapReady'></app-map>
```

This way the map div is only put into the dom if online.

And then in the **map.component.ts** we can wait until the component is placed into the DOM before loading the map itself.

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (typeof google !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('MapComponent.ngOnInit');
        this.loadMap();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just in case you'd like to make it a static function, which always returns a promise, but only gets the api once.

```js
const url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=__onGoogleMapsLoaded&ey=YOUR_API_KEY';
    
export class GoogleMapsLoader {
  private static promise;
  public static load() {

    // First time 'load' is called?
    if (!GoogleMapsLoader.promise) {

      // Make promise to load
      GoogleMapsLoader.promise = new Promise((resolve) => {

        // Set callback for when google maps is loaded.
        window['__onGoogleMapsLoaded'] = (ev) => {
          console.log('google maps api loaded');
          resolve(window['google']['maps']);
        };

        // Add script tag to load google maps, which then triggers the callback, which resolves the promise with windows.google.maps.
        console.log('loading..');
        let node = document.createElement('script');
        node.src = url;
        node.type = 'text/javascript';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
      });
    }

    // Always return promise. When 'load' is called many times, the promise is already resolved.
    return GoogleMapsLoader.promise;
  }
}
```

This is how you can get the api in other scripts:

```js
GoogleMapsLoader.load()
  .then((_mapsApi) => {
    debugger;
    this.geocoder       = new _mapsApi.Geocoder();
    this.geocoderStatus = _mapsApi.GeocoderStatus;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'm currently using:

```js
loadMapsScript(): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (document.querySelectorAll(`[src="${mapsScriptUrl}"]`).length) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      document.body.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement('script'), {
        type: 'text/javascript',
        src: mapsScriptUrl,
        onload: doMapInitLogic();
      }));
    }
  });
}
```

See my more comprehensive instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064697/how-to-install-typescript-typings-for-google-maps/42733315#42733315)

Comment: Can you provide a full example? And how would it work if I have 3rd party libraries dependent on google maps (i.e. js-map-label). Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378356) for reference

Comment: @MohammadAli, I've provided a link in my answer. I'd suggest loading both the scripts in a route resolver. First load the maps script, and then load the 3rd party script. Something like:
`loadGoogleMapsScript().switchMap(() => loadThirdPartyScript()));`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Google maps has the url so I can use above code, but how would I go about loadThirdPartyScript logic if 3rd party plugins were in node modules folder?