# TypeScript Error: Cannot find namespace 'google'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, typescript-typings

I have project angular-cli

**~root~/src/typings.json**

```
{
  "globalDevDependencies": {
    "angular-protractor": "registry:dt/angular-protractor#1.5.0+20160425143459",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "selenium-webdriver": "registry:dt/selenium-webdriver#2.44.0+20160317120654"
  },
  "globalDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160602141504",
    "google.maps": "registry:dt/google.maps#3.20.0+20160914131659"
  }
}
```

**~root~/typings/index.d.ts**

```
/// <reference path="globals/angular-protractor/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/google.maps/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/hammerjs/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/jasmine/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/selenium-webdriver/index.d.ts" />
```

**~root~/src/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types",
      "../typings"
    ],
    "files": [
      "../typings/index.d.ts"
    ]
  }
}
```

After run **ng serve**
I have error message in console

> ERROR in [default]
>   F:~root~\src\app\ui\google-map\map-marker\map-marker.directive.ts:7:26
>
> Cannot find namespace 'google'

and

> ERROR in [default]
>   ~root~\src\app\trip-entry-page\trip-entry-page.component.ts:188:21
>
> Cannot find name 'google'

**~root~\src\app\ui\google-map\map-marker\map-marker.directive.ts:7:26**

```
... 
@Input() veyoMapMarker: google.maps.MarkerOptions 
...
```

**~root~\src\app\trip-entry-page\trip-entry-page.component.ts:188:21**

```
... 
if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) { 
...
```

After build app correct working

How me resolve this Error messages?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Did the below answer help you? If so can you mark it as the accepted answer so others can find it.

Comment: Please refer to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42733315/1087131
I'm using CLI RC0.

Comment: "ERROR TS6137: Cannot import type declaration files. Consider importing 'googlemaps' instead of '@types/googlemaps'."

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A bit of a late response but I had a similar issue using **Angular CLI RC.0**.

It turned out that I hadn't install and imported the typings, which can be done as follows:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/googlemaps

import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
```

Comment: Aren't typings NOT supposed to be imported? I mean I haven't had to import any other typings I have installed.

Comment: Usually I don't import typings, because I have the npm library in my node_modules. This time, we need to download the google maps script at runtime so that's why the typings need to separately installed imported. See my complete answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064697/how-to-install-typescript-typings-for-google-maps/42733315#42733315

Comment: `Cannot import type declaration files. Consider importing 'googlemaps' instead of '@types/googlemaps'`. But the folder exists `node_modules/@types/googlemaps` with the index.d.ts file. -.-

Answer (score 9):

I was facing same problem and what I did was, I just removed these

```
import { } from 'googlemaps';
declare var google: any;
```

from my component.ts and add 
    "types": [
                "googlemaps"
              ]
in my tsconfig.app.json
.
.
Now my tsconfig.app.json looks like this.

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
        "module": "es2015",
        "types": [
            "googlemaps"
          ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "test.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

And its working perfectly.

Comment: This solved the issue for me in vuejs

Answer (score 4):

I run on the same issue but I installed the recommended package from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/using-typescript#getting_started)

```sh
npm i -D @types/google.maps
```

and then in my file or in the main file you can import it as follows

```
import '@types/google.maps';
```

this approach solves my issue with the `google.maps` namespace and its types.

Regards.

Comment: Using Vue3 + Vite I had to add `import '@types/google.maps'` in my `src/types/global.d.ts` file and it solved the issue. Thanks! Before, I added `"types": ["google.maps"]` in my `tsconfig.app.json` file but it only worked for `.vue` files.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone in Vue js facing this issue, you can add the following line at the top of your script section.  Make sure you have installed `@types/googlemaps`.

`/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />`

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks. The only difference is that I'm using the `@types/google.maps` package. As soon as I dropped this comment at the top of my util file, the errors were gone.

Answer (score 2):

In IONIC 4 I fixed it by installing **@types/google-maps** not **@types/googlemaps**

just run this

```
npm install @types/google-maps --save
```

and import **google** in your component using

```
import { google } from "google-maps";
```

Answer (score 2):

For Angular 9.****

I tried installing @types/googlemaps, It did not work for me.

I downgrade it to "@types/googlemaps": "3.39.12" then worked perfectly fine.

this is my code

In tsconfig.app.json (add googlemaps to types array)

```
"types": [
      "googlemaps"
    ]
```

In app module.ts

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
.
.
.
.
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: '...KEY...',
      libraries: ['places']
    })
  ],
```

To downgrade @types/googlemaps, go to pakage.json file in the project root folder and change @types/googlemaps version to "3.39.12". it's better if you delete files form

```
node_module -> @types -> googlemaps
```

Then in the terminal enter

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

1. All you need to do is import the package by:

   ```
   npm install @types/google-maps --save
   ```
2. Add `"types": [ "googlemaps" ]` in my tsconfig.app.json . . Now my tsconfig.app.json looks like this:

   ```
   {
       "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
       "compilerOptions": {
           "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
           "module": "es2015",
           "types": [
               "googlemaps"
             ]
       },
       "exclude": [
           "test.ts",
           "**/*.spec.ts"
       ]
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the below command in a node prompt...

```
typings install dt~google.maps --global --save
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with angular 7.
I did not need to import anything just run `npm install @types/googlemaps` again and if there is any vulnerabilities, run `npm audit fix` or `npm audit fix --force` if needed.

After I did so, everything worked fine for me...