# Typescript Error Cannot find name 'google' in ionic2 when using googlemaps javascript API

Tags: google-maps, angular, typescript, ionic2, typescript-typings

I am following Joshua Morony's Getting Started with Google Maps in Ionic 2 video tutorial. 
I want to use google maps in my application and i end up with a typescript error. this is a part of the
**pages/home/home.ts file**

```
initMap(){
let latLng= new google.maps.LatLng(6.929848, 79.857407);

let mapOpt={
  center : latLng,
  zoom : 15,
  mapTypeId :google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

this.map= new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement,mapOpt);}
```

I tried `npm install --save @types/googlemaps`,

but it still gives me the same typescript error **Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'google'**

Comment: The problem with the 2 existing answers is that they defeat the point of having `npm install --save @types/googlemaps`.  You are saying you have this, they are saying use `any`. It doesn't solve the problem. You can even right click in your IDE and see the `google` declarations, but Ionic2 doesn't see it.

Comment: It worked to me in Ionic 3,refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084724/types-googlemaps-index-d-ts-is-not-a-module/51169121#51169121

Answer (score 25):

I solved it by installing:

```
$npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev
```

Comment: Worked for me 2 :)

Comment: @Eli I stuck with the same problem, can u help me.

Comment: That repo moved. Its now

`npm i @types/google.maps`

Answer (score 15):

To expand on the answer from @suraj, you should have:

```
declare var google;
```

outside of the class you are trying to use it in.

Just like in the Josh Morony video, I put it beneath the imports but before the class declaration and annotations (`@Injectable()` and so forth).  I suppose it would still work if you put it above the imports or beneath the end of the class (and still outside of the class), if you were so inclined for whatever reason.

Answer (score 11):

```
npm install --save-dev @types/googlemaps

import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42733622/6517383)

**Or**

in your `component.ts` file of your page declare it like this

`declare var google;` before `export class component {}`

An easy way **Angular 6+** available in typescript is:

> You only have to add this line at the beginning (meaning
> line 1, with nothing before) of your Typescript file :
>
> `/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />`

And then

`import {RemainingItems} from 'whicheverfolderyouwant';`

[Updated from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51169121/6517383)

Answer (score 8):

You have to install types:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/googlemaps
```

And in your Typescript file where you use the namespace 'google':

[Angular 6+] Add this line at the beginning:

```
/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />
```

[Angular 5-] Add this line:

```
import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
```

[from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51169121/2736742)

Answer (score 2):

Newer version!

`@types/googlemaps` has been deprecated, instead, you need to install a different library:

`npm install @types/google.maps`

and at the very first line in your file, you will need to add a triple-slash directive:

`/// <reference types="@types/google.maps" />`

Comment: I'm at Angular v14 w `"@types/google.maps": "^3.51.0"`. Followed exactly instruction, `const map = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();` still receives `TS2663: Cannot find name 'google'`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to do some thing extra Just go into **index.d.ts** and paste this **before declare namespace google.maps**

```
declare module 'googlemaps';
```