# @types/googlemaps/index.d.ts' is not a module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I want to use the Google Maps API with my Angular project, so I used these two commands to install npm packages:

```
npm install @agm/core --save-dev
npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev
```

I added this line to my component:

```
import {} from "@types/googlemaps";
```

But I see these 2 errors in VS Code:

```
[ts] File 'h:/Angular Projects/Breakfast/client/breakfast/node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts' is not a module.
[ts] Cannot import type declaration files. Consider importing 'googlemaps' instead of '@types/googlemaps'.
```

I added these lines

```
"types": ["googlemaps"]
"moduleResolution": "node"
```

to tsconfig.json and tsconfig.spec.json, but still no luck. On Chrome Dev Tools, I see the below error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined
```

Angular version 6
Typescript Version 2.9.2

I tried from  Angular 5, too.

Comment: Thanks @CodeSpy. your FreakyJolly's example worked perfeclty.... saved me hours of trouble!

Answer (score 146):

Thanks to this documentation link : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html

[Angular 6+] You only have to add this line at the **beginning** (meaning line 1, with nothing before) of your Typescript file :

```
/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />
```

[Angular 5-] You only have to add this line anywhere in your Typescript file imports :

```
import {} from "googlemaps";
```

Thanks to the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52571177/1028679), you may also need to add a file `<root>/index.d.ts` containing (didn't need it though in my case) :

```
declare module 'googlemaps';
```

Comment: Where should I add this line ?
in my component ts file ? or html file ?

Comment: @HosseinBajan Well.. the question is angular6+ .. But I edited my answer to clarify it

Comment: The triple slash works, but WHY doesn't the normal import statement work? It's this kind of crap that just makes Angular painful to work with.

Comment: What? Why did this work?! What the heck? Umm... thanks?

Comment: The Angular 6+ option may not be a good idea, TS docs say:

--- Use these directives only when you’re authoring a d.ts file by hand.---

So it´s not supposed to be used in ".ts" file, only "d.ts" files.

Comment: For [Angular 6+] it only worked with adding at beginning of my Typescript file:

/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />

(with "@types/" added).

Comment: @FlorianD. thanks, both works for me, strange. But it makes more sense with `@types`

Comment: Triple-Slash Directive worked for me on NG 6.1.1. Thanks!

Comment: Where should I add this line ? in my component ts file ? or html file ?

Comment: @SaravananNandhan Not sure I can be more explicit than what I put in my answer `You only have to add this line at the beginning of your Typescript file`

Comment: The file Cetia is referring to is any .ts file you need to use googlemaps. But you need to add it to the top of the file, before any imports, line 1

Comment: This also worked for me on Angular 8. Thank you so much!

Comment: Worked for me here as well, however it already worked in my local environment but the build server crashed, adding the reference did the trick

Answer (score 38):

The import can be simplified as follows:

```
import {} from "googlemaps";
```

**Create** a file at your projects root directory named `index.d.ts` and paste the following:

```
declare module 'googlemaps';
```

The created file needs to be located directory in the `src` folder

I found this article about what is the purpose of that file

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3169-adding-custom-typings-files-d-ts-in-an-angular-2-typescript-application.htm

Comment: Just tried this approach (on Vue.js) project and it worked, bear in mind for my case I needed to place this hack under the `src/` folder, one level down from tsconfig

Comment: This worked for me on Angular 6 - needed to do both. I think this should be the recommended answer.

Comment: Works in Angular 8

Comment: Confirmed on Angular 9, it's the people's chosen answer.

Comment: this is working. got an error on my previous project angular 5. perfectly works

Answer (score 17):

In my Angular 7+ project

`$ npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev`

In tsconfig.app.json

```
"types": [
      "googlemaps"
]
```

Thank you the link below
https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-6-add-google-maps-in-angular-2-plus-applications-using-angular-google-maps-module-agm-core-easily/#more-2316

Comment: This solution worked for me out of all the solutions.

Comment: This solution worked for me on Angular 8. Thank you so much!
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/37932

Answer (score 13):

I just created a index.d.ts in my src folder and added

> declare module 'googlemaps';

It solved the issue

Answer (score 12):

It works fine

```
npm install --save-dev @types/googlemaps
At the beggining of your component file, type:
/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />
```

Answer (score 7):

For me in Angular 6, it worked when I **only** used

```
/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />
```

Answer (score 5):

In my angular 6+ project I've solved the problem declaring the googlemaps namespace in the top of the typescript file with this line:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts"/>
```

with this done you must not import googlemaps in other ways and then it works. Use the correct path to your node_modules folder.

For further information and references about namespace usage in Typescript [here the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html).

Comment: Using Angular 7.2, this was the solution of the ones listed on this page that successfully worked for me. Trying the additional index.d.ts' in a `types` directory wasn't successful, nor was importing {} etc.

Comment: I just upgraded from Angular 7 to 8 to 9, and ran into this same issue.  This answer from @bertonc96 was the only solution that resolved my issue, and the comment from Jamie Love was helpful as it puts things in the right context (ie, try this solution without any of the other suggestions provided in the other answers).  The only thing i'd clarify is that the typescript file to include the code above is your component file in which you're using the googlemaps API. In my case, I'm using it in a directive.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried this solution
I think it is the best because I didn't need to edit at packages
and someone writes it without classification

1. `npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev`
2. add `"compilerOptions": { "types": ["googlemaps"] }`  in tsconfig.app.json file
3. Dont forget to remove `import {} from 'googlemaps';` from your code.

**FYI**: you must restart the server `ng serve`

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this error next way:

After you have installed

> npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev

Go to **src/tsconfig.app.json** and add next line:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "types": [
         "googlemaps"
    ],
    ...,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not on the root.
You just need to add the code below on this file:
**node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts**

```
declare module 'googlemaps';
```

Comment: We can't update in our dependencies because of versioning, this could not be a solution

Answer (score -1):

```
    import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
    declare var google;
    
    
     constructor(private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader) {
         this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
              var mapProp = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(9.93040049002793, -84.09062837772197),
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              };
              this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, mapProp);
            });
        
          }
    
    //Hope it helps
```

Answer (score -1):

We already had

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
```

So adding

```
declare var google;
```

Was all we needed to add to the module

Comment: There are **11 existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with over **one hundred votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.