# "Cannot find name 'google'" when trying to access Google Maps API

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm doing this tutorial [on Google Maps into Ionic](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-google-maps-and-geolocation-in-ionic-with-capacitor/) and I did everything, amended other mistakes but I get this error:

> [14:33:14]  transpile started ...
>   [14:33:27]  typescript: ...ncisco/ionic/ionic-google-maps-example/src/components/google-maps/google-maps.ts, line: 157
>              Cannot find name 'google'.
>
> L157:                  let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
>   position.coords.longitude);
>
> [14:33:27]  typescript:
>   ...ncisco/ionic/ionic-google-maps-example/src/components/google-maps/google-maps.ts,
>   line: 164
>   Cannot find name 'google'.
>
> L164:                  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.element.nativeElement, mapOptions);
>        L165:                  resolve(true);

I followed the advice from the tutorial  and ran:

> npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev

However, it didn't change anything. I've seen other post suggesting running a command with typings to install it but still it doesn't see it.

Comment: can you post your `types` entry from both your `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig-app.json` ? Maybe try explicitly defining the types there. Also, if using the CLI, try killing your server and re-serving the app to rebuild what types are imported. Also, can you post which version of Angular you're using?

Comment: my tsconfig.json doesn't have a types section. How do I set that?

Comment: My angular version in package.json is 5.2

Comment: By deafult, it's the `typeRoots` entry. Sorry, should have clarified that.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084724/types-googlemaps-index-d-ts-is-not-a-module/51169121#51169121 -- has solutions for both ng 5 and 6

Comment: do you have google required into your project in main.ts or vendor.ts. You have the package, but that just means it's in your node_modules. You also need to require the package to bring it into your project.