# Ionic Capacitor Google Maps error (@capacitor/google-maps)

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, capacitor

I want to include Google Maps in an ionic capacitor angular project so I followed their [documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/google-maps) to do so. But when I build I get the following error:

```
Error: node_modules/@capacitor/google-maps/dist/typings/definitions.d.ts:1:23 - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'google.maps'.
[ng] 1 /// <reference types="google.maps" />
```

I searched everywhere, checked the documentation, even followed the answers in this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084724/types-googlemaps-index-d-ts-is-not-a-module) none which seemed to help:

UPDATE:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "^4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/browser": "^4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/camera": "^4.1.3",
    "@capacitor/core": "^4.3.0",
    "@capacitor/geolocation": "^4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/google-maps": "^4.3.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "^4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^4.3.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.1.12",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^3.0.6",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^13.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "swiper": "^8.4.4",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^6.0.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "3.2.13",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that this is a [bug](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/issues/1261) in their new version 4.3.0, downgrading the package to 4.2.1 fixed the issue: npm i @capacitor/google-maps@4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

**You could try:**

1. Delete package-lock.json
2. delete node_modules Folder
3. Run npm install

**or when you have dependencie Problems that you want to fix later**

```
npm install -f
```

Comment: I tried it a couple of times and it is still giving me the same error

Comment: Could you please provide the package.json ?

Comment: I have updated the question with package.json file