# Google Map not showing up Javascript Ionic 4

Tags: typescript, google-maps, ionic4

I've been trying to insert a Google Map on my Ionic 4 Webiste, but I've been unable to because the map is not showed up.

Here's my code below

```
  ionViewDidEnter(){
    console.log('creating map')
    // var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.305, -76.617);
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });    
}
```

This is how I'm inserting it on the HTML file

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Any hint or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so the hook gets called right? also what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josh Morony has a great [blog post](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-google-maps-and-geolocation-in-ionic-with-capacitor/) that walks through how to build out a map component. Basically it goes something like this:

Install the types for Google maps

```
 npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev
```

Initialize the map in your component

```
/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor() {}

  async ngAfterViewInit() {
    const googleMaps = await getGoogleMaps("YOUR-API-KEY-HERE");
    this.initMap();
  }
  initMap() {
    const POSITION = {lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036};

    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: POSITION || { lat: 22, lng: 22 }
    });
  }
}

function getGoogleMaps(apiKey: string): Promise<any> {
  const win = window as any;
  const googleModule = win.google;
  if (googleModule && googleModule.maps) {
    return Promise.resolve(googleModule.maps);
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${apiKey}`;
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.onload = () => {
      const googleModule2 = win.google;
      if (googleModule2 && googleModule2.maps) {
        resolve(googleModule2.maps);
      } else {
        reject("google maps not available");
      }
    };
  });
}
```

The first line `/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />` of the component is to address a Typescript related issue (details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173662/typescript-error-cannot-find-name-google-in-ionic2-when-using-googlemaps-javas))

Lastly, make make sure your CSS is setup to render the map.

```
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: contents;
}
```

Hope this helps.