# Angular2 Cannot find namespace 'google'

Tags: google-maps, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-google-maps

I am working with `angular2-google-maps` and latest version of Angular2. I am trying to convert some of the local map component functions into services in their own file `maps.service.ts`. For example:

map.component.ts

```
getGeoLocation(lat: number, lng: number) {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    let request = { latLng: latlng };
    geocoder.geocode(request, (results, status) => {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        let result = results[0];
        if (result != null) {
          this.fillInputs(result.formatted_address);
        } else {
          alert("No address available!");
        }
      }
    });
}
}
```

Into something like: `maps.service.ts`

```
getGeoLocation(lat: number, lng: number): Observable<google.maps.GeocoderResult[]> {
    let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    let request = { latLng: latlng };
    return new Observable((observer: Observer<google.maps.GeocoderResult[]>) => {
        geocoder.geocode({ request }, (
            (results: google.maps.GeocoderResult[], status: google.maps.GeocoderStatus) => {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    observer.next(results);
                    observer.complete();
                } else {
                    console.log('Geocoding service failed due to: ' +status);
                    observer.error(status);
                }
            }
        ));
    });
}
```

The issue I'm getting is that `google` variable is not being recognized when I try to use `Observer<google.maps.GeocoderResult[]>`. I have `declare var google: any;` outside of the service class as well.

The `google` variable works in my `map.componenet.ts` but doesn't get recognized in the `maps.service.ts`.

Comment: Where do you import `google`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Within AppModule: `    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: '--key--',
      libraries: ['places']
    })`

Comment: You need a TypeScript import as well that provides `google`. Seems you copied the code from somewhere. Can you please post a link?

Comment: I have added `    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>` and tried adding the google-maps typings globally as well.

Comment: `AgmCoreModule` doesn't seem to provide anything related to `Geocoder`

Answer (score 111, accepted):

## Angular 6 & 7 steps (should also work for every other Angular version):

1. `npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev`
2. Add `googlemaps` to the types array in both files`tsconfig.app.json` respectively in `tsconfig.spec.json` (save both files)
3. At the top of your controller.ts

```
/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />
```

4. Restart npm server

The `types` array should look like these in both files

```json
{ 
    "compilerOptions": { 
        "types": ["googlemaps","othertype",...]
    }
}
```

> You can delete both declaration types from the components: `import {} from '@types/googlemaps';` `declare var google: any;` You don't have to include any of them.

PS: If you are using agm-s GoogleMapsAPIWrapper.getNativeMap() you must convert the map object before you use it. For example turning on the traffic layer:

```
this.apiWrapper.getNativeMap().then(map => {
    this.trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    const gMap: any = map;
    this.trafficLayer.setMap(gMap as google.maps.Map);
});
```

Comment: Dammit I am still getting `error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'google'.` I just need to add `"compilerOptions": { "types": ["googlemaps"]}`, right? Does not work for me .. :/

Comment: Alright I had to restart `ng server` then it worked!

Comment: I found that I also had to move my Google Maps <script> tag from within my component into index.html's <head>. Until I did this *no* solutions worked for me.

Comment: Worked for angular 5 too!

Comment: Working on Angular 7 here. Thank you!

Comment: Using Angular 8. Works for me! Thanks

Comment: why do I have to add to types in .spec and .app, if I already added in typeroots?

Comment: I'm using google pay and this solution worked for me in vue as well. thanks.

Comment: 2022: The package has a dot it is `@types/google.maps` and in the compilerOptions should be `"types": ["google.maps"]}`

Comment: @Ali thanks for your live saver comment, I have updated the answer

Answer (score 61):

I was facing the same problem 
I tried :

```
declare var google: any;
```

But it didn't work for me .
I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42733622/1880686) and it worked for me .
 First make sure you installed the typings for google maps
 `npm install @types/googlemaps --save --dev`

> --dev flag is deprecated. Use `npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev`

And Then in your Controller

```
import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
```

Comment: This worked for me...just want to add that in Angular 2, I added `import {} from '@types/googlemaps';` to the same file after `import { NguiMapModule} from '@ngui/map';` in my shared.module.ts.

Comment: It seems like Typescript linting doesn't like `import {} from '@types/googlemaps';` anymore, but suggests: 

`import { } from 'googlemaps'`

Comment: can somebody explain (or even better to drive me to ts doc page) about this "empty" import. Nevertheless it works it looks like unused import. Wondered why does this help...

Answer (score 20):

To prevent more suffering of anyone else with this issue.

```
npm install @google/maps
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google/maps

THEN:

```
import { google } from '@google/maps';
```

Basically we're importing the google object from the package `@google/maps`.

Tested in 2018 after `@types/googlemaps` stopped working.

Comment: Note: I had to use `declare var google: any` in conjunction with this technique.

Comment: Worked for me without any `declare var google: any`

Comment: looks like that package is now deprecated, replaced by `@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js`

Comment: I had to add "declare var google: any;" to make it work.

Comment: The `@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js` is ment to be use in `node.js` and shouldn't be use on the client side, as mentioned [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js)

Answer (score 13):

Add

```
declare var google: any;
```

after the TypeScript imports

See also https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps/issues/689

Comment: worked in Angular 14

Answer (score 11):

```
ERROR: [ts] Cannot import type declaration files. Consider importing ‘googlemaps’ instead of ‘@types/googlemaps’
```

**solution**: change `import {} from ‘@types/googlemaps’;` for

```
/// <reference types=”@types/googlemaps” />
```

---

```
ERROR: while compiling, error TS2304: Cannot find name ‘google’.
```

**solution**: add `declare var google: any;` below @types/googlemaps reference

---

```
ERROR: while compiling error TS2503: Cannot find namespace ‘google’.
```

**solution**: Add to tsconfig.app.json : `"types": ["googlemaps"]`
and restart

---

> ERROR: map doesn’t load correctly and in the web browser console you
> read “Google  Maps Javascript API Warning: NoApiKeys”

**solution**: add a valid api key inside the javascript file in index.html, should
look like this
`<script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"></script>`
you can get an API key from here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

---

```
ERROR:Cannot find name 'google'
```

Well, this is in case you just installed the types with:

```
npm i -D @types/google.maps
```

and you tried to used them. Sometimes in tsconfig.app.json there is empty type array, which prevents the automatic import. Remove "types": [] and could work. It worked for me once.

Comment: good answer for showing all the possibilities including the one that fixed it for me - tsconfig.app.json, which also avoided installing @google/maps

Comment: Don't forget to restart your dev environment. I've found that is necessary to get the reference seen.

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar problem with Angular 6, and I did all the possible solutions mentioned above but no luck.
Finally, I manage to solve this problem by adding `googlemaps` into `types` inside `tsconfig.app` and `tsconfig.spec` files.
Hope it helps for others.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was getting 2 types of errors:

- Cannot find namespace google
- Cannot find name google

Since in my code I am using:

```
let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(...)

let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
```

So fixed it by adding this:

```
declare var google: any;

declare namespace google.maps.places {
    export interface PlaceResult { geometry }
}
```

Comment: I just had types = ["google.maps"] in my tsconfig.app.json and all was working fine until I tried to add prerendering via Universal: the SSR server would not build with the error  `Cannot find namespace 'google'.`. This fix worked for me, I just had to modify the namespace declaration to include the functions I'm using, ie; 
```declare namespace google.maps.places {export interface Autocomplete { getPlace }}``` in one file and ```declare namespace google.maps.places { export interface ComponentRestrictions { country }}``` in another.

Answer (score 4):

Install [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/using-typescript)

```
npm i -D @types/google.maps
```

Add this line at the beginning (meaning line 1, with nothing before) of your Typescript file :

```
/// <reference types="@types/google.maps" />
```

[Triple Slash Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51169121/5806017)

Answer (score 3):

It is working for me also:

First install the `typings` for google maps in cmd on root of project

```
npm install @types/googlemaps --save --dev
```

And then add in your `.ts` component file below:

```
import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was

```
npm install --save-dev @types/googlemaps
```

and then at the very top of your .ts page add this

```
/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Straight solution, Add "googlemaps" to types array in tsconfig.app.json. And I didnt need to declare anything like, declare var google: any;. Just adding googlemaps in tsconfig works.

```
"types": ["googlemaps"]
```

Comment: Simplest and best working advise here.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is struggling with this because Webstorm undescores the code even after installing types and adding them to tsconfig... restart the Webstorm. It took me an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Noting solved the problem for me.
After following the top rated answer still didn't worked only worked after adding this

`npm i @types/googlemaps@3.39.13 --save-dev`

make sure you run this before `ng serve` and make sure to restart the server if its running.

Answer (score -1):

```
`
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { GoogleMapsAPIWrapper, MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
declare var google: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MapService extends GoogleMapsAPIWrapper {
  geocoder: Promise<any>;
  constructor(private __loader: MapsAPILoader, private __zone: NgZone) {
    super(__loader, __zone);
    this.geocoder = this.__loader.load().then(() => new google.maps.Geocoder());
  }

  getLatLan(address: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.geocoder.then((geocoder) => {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, (results, status) => {
          if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            observer.next(results[0].geometry.location);
            observer.complete();
          } else {
            console.error('Error - ', results, ' & Status - ', status);
            observer.next({});
            observer.complete();
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
}`
```

This is a service with a method to get the address and return lan and lat.