# Angular Googlemaps typing fails unit tests

Tags: angular, google-maps, unit-testing, typescript

I'm using the [@typings/googlemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/googlemaps) typing for an Angular application, which when serving runs and returns no warnings or errors.

However, I'd like to create some unit tests for my components, and Karma cant launch, producing errors like:

```
ERROR in: ... Cannot find namespace 'google'.
```

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42394697/angular2-cannot-find-namespace-google) and others like it to install the typing and continue my work.

Adding `declare var google:any` to the *typings.d.ts* won't work since it is already declared in the typing file, and the 'Duplicate identifier' compile error is given.

Any suggestions?

EDIT 1:

An excerpt of code on my *google-maps.service.ts*, one of the files giving an error. I don't import googlemaps, as it's not necessary since it's a typing by my understanding.

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {environment} from "../../../environments/environment";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {forEach} from "@angular/router/src/utils/collection";

@Injectable()
export class GoogleMapsService {
    scriptLoadingPromise: Promise<void>;

    api_key = '';
    url = '';

    map: google.maps.Map;
    markers: Array<google.maps.Marker>;
    bounds: google.maps.LatLngBounds;
    geocoder: google.maps.Geocoder;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.api_key = '1234';
        this.url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js';
        this.markers = new Array();
        // Loading script
        this.load().then(() => {
            this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        });
    }
}

getScriptSrc(callbackName: string): string {
    return `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${this.api_key}&callback=${callbackName}`;
};

onReady(): Promise<void> {
    return this.scriptLoadingPromise;
};

load(): Promise<void> {
    if (this.scriptLoadingPromise) {
        return this.scriptLoadingPromise;
    }

    const script = window.document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    const callbackName = 'googleMapsServiceCallback';
    script.src = this.getScriptSrc(callbackName);

    this.scriptLoadingPromise = new Promise<void>((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
        (<any>window)[callbackName] = () => {
            resolve();
        };

        script.onerror = (error: Event) => {
            reject(error);
        };
    });
    window.document.body.appendChild(script);

    return this.scriptLoadingPromise;
}
```

EDIT 2: I updated the code above. It uses the same structure as the [Angular 2+ Maps](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps) project, with reference to the [code here](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/blob/master/packages/core/services/maps-api-loader/lazy-maps-api-loader.ts). There aren't any pre-compilation errors thrown because the 'google' keyword is accounted for in the typing.

Comment: Can you share your code - for example, in the file generating this error do you have an import for googlemaps?

Comment: @Fenton - Added some code

Answer (score 0):

You will need to hint to the compiler that you are using google maps... for example using an import:

```
import { googlemaps } from 'googlemaps';
```

Or using a `///<reference...` comment if you aren't using modules.

Comment: Hey @Fenton - this won't resolve my issue, I don't use 'googlemaps' as a package anywhere in my code, and even if I add an import for 'google', I get an error saying the 'google' package cannot be found :(

Comment: WIll update my post & code further to include some additional pointers.