# Angular 6 - @types/googlemaps/index.d.ts' is not a module

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps

i just updated some packages in my package.json file. Then after running `npm install` i run `ng serve`. However i am now getting the following errors.

```
ERROR in ... File '.../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts' is not a module.
... error TS6137: Cannot import type declaration files. Consider importing 'googlemaps' instead of '@types/googlemaps'
```

I tried the suggested solution here - [@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts' is not a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084724/types-googlemaps-index-d-ts-is-not-a-module) adding `/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />` at the top of my component.ts file however this did not fix my problem and the error persists.

---

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.18",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.7",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/chartjs": "0.0.31",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.13",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.108",
    "auth0-js": "^9.5.1",
    "auth0-lock": "^11.6.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "d3": "^5.1.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "json-formatter-js": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "npm": "^6.0.0",
    "progressbar.js": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
    "ua-parser-js": "^0.7.18",
    "wordcloud": "^1.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
    "@angular/cli": "6.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.7",
    "@types/d3": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/d3-dsv": "^1.0.31",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.1",
    "source-map-explorer": "^1.5.0",
    "ts-node": "~6.0.3",
    "tslint": "~5.10.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": ["googlemaps"],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**component.ts**

```
/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { } from '@types/googlemaps';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts' is not a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084724/types-googlemaps-index-d-ts-is-not-a-module)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably don't need this line in your component.ts file (It's only for Angular <6):

```
import { } from '@types/googlemaps';
```

Here's an (basic/minimal) example for Angular 6:

```
/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />
map: google.maps.Map;
this.map = new google.maps.Map(....);
```

Basically, if you want to use it in Angular <6, you have to add it via the `import` method. In Angular 6+ you have to add it via the `reference` method. You shouldn't add both at the same time.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Yes that built, but why do i need to remove the import in place of the reference. I am use to installing a package and using import to use it.

Comment: Because you shouldn't add it twice / with different methods.  It's only a type and not the maps package itself. I assume you've added the maps via a script tag inside your index.html. If you want to use it as a package you'll have to import 'googlemaps' itself.

Comment: Ye i would prefer to use import rather than reference.

Answer (score 18):

For Angular6~

1. `npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev` or `yarn add @types/googlemaps`
2. Add `"googlemaps"` to `tsconfig.app.json` types array

[image: adding 'googlemaps' to tsconfig.app.json example (Line 6)]

3. Add `"googlemaps"` to `tsconfig.spec.json` types array

[image: adding 'googlemaps' to tsconfig.app.json example (Line 8)]

4. Add `/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />` on the first line of your component.ts file. This line will import @types/googlemaps. (Line1 of example below)
5. Declare google variable as `declare let google: any;` (Line6 of example below)

[image]

Ref:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52200117/10009565

Comment: bit of an overkill but it silences TS.

Comment: You dont have to do Step 1-4 when you do `declare let google: any;`. This will silence the compiler in any way and he will not care about anymore. I downvoted your answer. It does not add the typings, instead it just silences everything.