# how to perform reverse geocode in angular 7

Tags: angular7, angular-google-maps

I'm working with angular-google-map.I'm receving JSON data of lattitude and longitude.I want to get address of given lat and long.Is there any npm package for reverse geocoding . I tried reverse-geocoding but no use .it returns compilation error.
please help

Answer (score 1):

Native geocoding in AGM is coming soon. The code is in master, waiting for the next release.

If you need geocoding right now, you can do it manually, by waiting for a `mapReady` event

```js
function geocode() {
   new google.maps.Geocoder.geocode({});
}
```

```html
<agm-map (mapReady)="geocode()">
```

If you get `google` not recognized, add @types/googlemaps to package.json as per 
[Angular2 Cannot find namespace 'google'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42394697/angular2-cannot-find-namespace-google)

Comment: is there any other npm  package .