# Angular unit testing with custom typings gives Cannot find namespace

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular8

I am using custom typings for my angular project to avoid rework in client side for strict typings. However, it is not working while running unit tests.

I am not sure, how to bring this namespace while running unit tests. Below is the code we have

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  public employees: Company.Core.DTO.IEmployee[];
}
```

**SPEC**

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('SearchComponent',
  () => {

    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
    let component: AppComponent; 

    beforeEach(async(() => {
     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       declarations: [AppComponent],
       schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
       })
       .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
     component = fixture.componentInstance;
     fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

  });
```

**Typings** in file (app/typings/Company.typings.ts) autogenerated by [TypeLite](http://type.litesolutions.net/)

```
declare module Company.Core.DTO {
  interface IEmployee {
    Number: number;
    Age: number;    
    Name: string;   
  }
}
```

Error while executing unit test

> error TS2503: **Cannot find namespace Company**

This happens only during unit testing compilation. While running application, we are not getting this error.

Tried this [Angular2 Cannot find namespace 'google'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42394697/angular2-cannot-find-namespace-google/42416954#42416954) but no luck

**NPM packages**

```
Angular : 8.2.12
jasmine-core : ~3.5.0
karma: ^4.4.1
karma-jasmine : ~2.0.1
typescript: 3.5.3
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at your `tsconfig.json` and how it is configured (most likely) to include `Company.typings.ts`. Then look at your `tsconfig.spec.json` to include `Company.typings.ts` the same way. I believe you have to play around with `types` array or `typeroots` or `includes`.

[TypeScript 2: custom typings for untyped npm module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222162/typescript-2-custom-typings-for-untyped-npm-module)