# google maps with typescript

Tags: typescript, google-maps

I'm trying to include google maps javascript API into a project using Typescript and keep getting the error "**Cannot find namespace 'google'.ts(2503)**"

I am following the official documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api) and have used "Use Dynamic Library Import" method to include the script tag in my html file. I am using parcel to convert the .ts file into .js and start a local server. **If at this stage I open the chrome browser console and type "google" then it is accessible.**

For the next step, in my .ts file I included the code from the official docs:

```
let map: google.maps.Map; // Cannot find namespace 'google'.ts(2503)

async function initMap(): Promise<void> {
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps") as google.maps.MapsLibrary;
  map = new Map(document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement, {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  });
}

initMap();
```

In the official docs, uder the Typescript section (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/using-typescript), it says that "**types are automatically generated**" but I still explicitly download the type definitions using "**npm i -D @types/google.maps**" but still get an error.

If it helps, I have install Typescript and parcel globally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript Error: Cannot find namespace 'google'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39909544/typescript-error-cannot-find-namespace-google)

Comment: @admcfajn The official docs use "npm i -D @types/google.maps" NOT "npm install --save-dev @types/googlemaps". And yes, i tried installing the recommended type definitions but the error still persists.

Comment: Did you try adding to compilerOptions in tsconfig? And you've used `import '@types/google.maps';`?

Comment: @admcfajn I've literally just started learning Typescript so I don't know about the tsconfig file.  I haven't added the file or the import. In the official maps docs there's no mention of setting up the tsconfig file or import the types explicitly. If you look at my question, i've mentioned that the docs clearly specify that the types are automatically generated and i'm assuming that i don't have to import them then.

Comment: @admcfajn If you feel that the problem is because of the tsconfig file then can you please guide me about what to do and include in the file.

Comment: I finally got it to work! You do not have to explicitly install '@types/google.maps'! I just deleted the package.lock file, node_modules folder and then installed all the packages again. I also set a width and height in pixels (not percentages) for the div which will hold the map. The map is showing now, however, there is just one problem. When I open the .ts file where the map is being initialized, I still see the red squiggly line. I'm now sure that this is a linting error. Any ideas how I can get rid of this false positive???

Comment: Hello @falahmahmood what part of your code is showing the red squiggly line?

Comment: @Yrll The word "google" in the code sample shared in the question above. It says "Cannot find namespace 'google'.ts(2503)"

Comment: @Yrll I found the solution. You have to add "/// <reference types="@types/google.maps" />" as the first line the .ts file. Now the google namespace is available and I get no errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For everyone who is facing an error with the updated google maps javascript api, who simply need to follow the instructions from the official docs and remember to add `/// <reference types="@types/google.maps" />` **EXACTLY AS IS** as the first line in your typescript file where you're initializing the map. Now the google namespace error will be gone.

Kindly, go through my comments above if you're facing other issues. I've mentioned a few of the errors/issues I had to face and have also provided solutions for them.