# Type 'any' is not a constructor function type. class google.maps.OverlayView

Tags: google-maps, angular

What I want to implement is a piechart marker like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/FCPJM/16/) I cant figure out how to draw the overlay.I saw a similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40104288/angular2-how-to-setup-a-google-maps-overlayview-translate-js-prototype-into), but none of these answers work for me.
I am getting this error - "***Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.
class google.maps.OverlayView***"

```
 import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
    const chartsApi = 'https://www.google.com/jsapi';
    declare var google: any;
    declare var $: any;
    import { } from '@types/googlemaps'
    @Component({
        selector: 'chart-marker',
        templateUrl: './chart-marker.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./chart-marker.styles.scss']
    })

    export class ChartMarkerComponent {
        @Input() options: Object;
        @Input() data: Object;
        @Output() chartReady: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
        private divToDraw: any;
        private innerDiv: any;
        private chart: any;
        constructor() {
            this.loadCharts();
        }
// the code below is giving me this error 
        USGSOverlay = class extends google.maps.OverlayView {
            bounds_: any;
            image_: any;
            map_: any;
            div_: any;
            constructor(bounds, image, private map) {
                super();
                // Initialize all properties.

            }
            /**
             * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
             * added to the map.
             */
            onAdd() {

            };
            draw() {

            };
            // The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
            // we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
            onRemove() {

            };
        };
        private loadCharts() {
            if (typeof google === "undefined" || typeof google.charts === "undefined") {
                let node = document.createElement('script');
                node.src = chartsApi;
                node.type = 'text/javascript';
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(node);
                node.onload = () => {
                    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ['corechart'], "callback": this.drawChart.bind(this) });
                }
            }
        }
        private drawChart() {
            this.chartReady.emit(true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: I have edited my question to include the code.

Comment: What version of TS are you using v2.3?

Comment: "typescript": "2.1.6"

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that TypeScript doesn't recognize [your Google Maps API typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/googlemaps/index.d.ts) so it assumes what you are referring to is of type `any` which it doesn't allow to inherit from, hence the error message. As far as I know you can't import the typings but they are treated as `ambient` declarations in TS lingo - so having a `tsconfig.json` and the typings installed in your project directory should suffice.

I would recommend doing a minimal example without your Angular setup in place to see if TypeScript actually uses the provided typings, looking at the actual typings the class should be inheritable und usable in the way you're trying to do it.

Something like this in a single file should suffice to see whether TS is picking up your typings:

```
class extends google.maps.OverlayView {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }  
};
```