# Load Google Maps JS API in component [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How is it possible to load an external `js` file, from a url in an Angular component?

To be specific, I'm trying to load `google-maps-api` to my angular project. Currently, I'm doing it in my `index.html` like this:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Note: I'm aware of `angular-maps`. That's not an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution is to create the script tag dynamically in `ngAfterViewInit()`

```js
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
...

constructor(private @Inject(DOCUMENT) document, 
            private elementRef:ElementRef) {};

ngAfterViewInit() {
  var s = this.document.createElement("script");
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY";
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
}
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4903

**Update**

```html
<div id="map" #mapRef></div>
```

---

```js
export class GoogleComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("mapRef") mapRef: ElementRef;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showMap();
  }

  showMap() {
    console.log(this.mapRef.nativeElement);
    const location = { lat: 28.5355, lng: 77.3910 };
    var options = {
      center: location,
      zoom: 8
    }

    const map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement, options);
    this.addMarket(map, location);
  }
  addMarket(pos, map) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pos,
      map: map,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what about the `callback` part? How can i get notified when api is ready?

Comment: Thanks again, but the above code doesn't wait for `google.maps` to be loaded.

Comment: It will load once the js is loaded

Comment: Can you explain how? I'm confused.

Comment: @HamidAsghari : check out this link for working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dixbbi?file=app%2Fgoogle%2Fgoogle.component.ts

Comment: @HamidAsghari have you seen my demo

Comment: Thanks again. I will edit your answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 14):

You can use Promise to load google API asynchronously whenever you want.

```
// map-loader.service.ts
import ...
declare var window: any;

@Injectable()
export class MapLoader {

    private static promise;
    map: google.maps.Map;

    public static load() {
        if (!MapLoader.promise) { // load once
            MapLoader.promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
                window['__onGapiLoaded'] = (ev) => {
                    console.log('gapi loaded')
                    resolve(window.gapi);
                }
                console.log('loading..')
                const node = document.createElement('script');
                node.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<YOUR _API_KEY>&callback=__onGapiLoaded';
                node.type = 'text/javascript';
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
            });
        }

        return MapLoader.promise;
    }

    initMap(gmapElement, lat, lng) {

        return MapLoader.load().then((gapi) => {
            this.map = new google.maps.Map(gmapElement.nativeElement, {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                zoom: 12
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Component

```
//maps.component.ts

...
@Component({
  selector: 'maps-page',
  templateUrl: './maps.component.html'
})
export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {       

  @ViewChild('gmap') gmapElement: any;
  constructor(public mapLoader: MapLoader) { }

  ngOnInit() {

      this.mapLoader.initMap(this.gmapElement, -37.81, 144.96)  // await until gapi load
  }

  ...
}
```

Component HTML

```
// maps.component.html
<div #gmap ></div>
```

Don't forget to add CSS to the element.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer wasn't upvoted. I got my solution by looking at this code -- but I implemented in app.component.ts in ngOnInit(). Cheers!

Comment: replace "map: google.maps.Map;" with "map: any;" to prevent type errors. also add "window." before any "google.maps."

Comment: @desmati, it is to use @types/googlemaps in typescript. It will support auto-completion of google API. If you have an error, you may install @types/googlemaps.

Comment: The main answer doesn't work for me but this works, only add to your css by id: 
#map {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
Then add to node.src variable:
node.src +='&key=YOUR_KEY';

Comment: I presumed the person need this code, also know about CSS. Regarding key, google changed their policy and need API key. I will update the above code.

Comment: @John So, for adding markers we also create the function inside the service? It will be great if you can show how will you tackle adding, removing of Markers :)

Comment: @Aslam, It does not have to be in the service. You can use MapLoader.load().then((gapi)... in wherever you need like ngOnInit in component. Also after create google.maps object, assign it to something like GmapStoreService to be used in others.

Comment: @John. I have used above code in my angular app and its working fine but i want to use some other thing as well like pinView and its not working. Anybody can help ? const pinViewScaled =  google.maps.Marker.PinView({
        scale: 1.5,
      });
      const markerViewScaled =  google.maps.Marker.AdvancedMarkerView({
        map,
        position: { lat: 37.419, lng: -122.02 },
        content: pinViewScaled.element,
      });

Comment: @akshaysaxena, it sounds that your question is not relevant to this topic. Would you be able to create a question with your code and leave the url to me?