# How to apply a custom css to a google.maps.GroundOverlay in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to apply a specific style to a google.maps.GroundOverlay to rotate it.

```
function (imageUrl: string, bounds: google.maps.LatLngBounds, map: google.maps.Map){
  let overlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
    imageUrl,
    bounds);
  overlay.setMap(map);
  // looking for something like overlay.style.rotate = '45deg'
}
```

How to add a style to google.maps.GroundOverlay in Javascript?

Thanks

---

**Edit 1:**

So I was thinking to find the element in the dom like:

```
[...]
overlay.setMap(map);
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("img[src='" + imageUrl + "']"));
```

but curiously it returns an empty array even if when I look in the source of the browser and I m able to find the image...

I continue to search

Comment: Duplicate of [Google map: How to rotate \`groundoverlay\` need trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948764/google-map-how-to-rotate-groundoverlay-need-trick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, I had no other choice than creating a custom Overlay. Here is my solution mostly inspirered from [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40105921/6123422)

*rotated-overlay.ts*

```
export class CustomOverlay extends google.maps.OverlayView {
  private div;

  constructor(
    private bounds: google.maps.LatLngBounds,
    private image: string,
    private rotation: number
  ) {
    super();

    // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
    // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
    // method so we'll leave it null for now.
    this.div = null;
  }

  /**
   * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
   * added to the map.
   */
  onAdd() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
    div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';

    // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = this.image;
    img.style.width = '100%';
    img.style.height = '100%';
    img.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.appendChild(img);

    this.div = div;

    // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
    const panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
  };

  draw() {

    // We use the south-west and north-east
    // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
    // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
    const overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

    // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
    // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
    // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
    const sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds.getSouthWest());
    const ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds.getNorthEast());

    // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
    const div = this.div;
    div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
    div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
    div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
    div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
    div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + this.rotation + 'deg)';
  };

  // The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
  // we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
  onRemove() {
    this.div.parentNode.removeChild(this.div);
    this.div = null;
  };
};
```

map-component.ts

```
public addOverlay(imageUrl: string, rotation: number, bounds: google.maps.LatLngBounds, map: google.maps.Map){
  let overlay = new CustomOverlay(
    bounds,
    imageUrl,
    rotation,
    
  );
  overlay.setMap(map);
}
```