# Add image overlay to Google Maps with rotate and tilt

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to overlay an image onto a Google Map and I am using the instructions found here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple

When I try using the 'heading' attribute, the map correctly rotates, however, so does the image. I have tried using an image transform to rotate the picture, but I end up with a white box on the map.

Below is my javascript

```
let historicalOverlay;
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 24.960864, lng: 55.150841 },
    zoom: 16,
    tilt: 47.5,
    heading: 120,
    mapId: "90f87356969d889c",
  });
    const imageBounds = {
    north: 24.9717265,
    south: 24.9500015,
    east: 55.161841,
    west: 55.139841,
  };

  historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay("https://res.cloudinary.com/defmmlrqg/image/upload/a_120/v1646695548/test/img32_iidhie.jpg", imageBounds);
  historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
}
```

And this is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tilt and Rotation</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&v=beta&channel=2" async></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ef79tL45/21/

Comment: I don't see any issues rotating the image with a css transform operation, however the image looks like "45 degree" imagery, which doesn't rotate but so well on the map.  How did you attempt to rotate it?  Do you have a "flat" image that would rotate better over the map?

Comment: Hi, no I dont have a flat image. The only one I have is with the tilt. The image is being served from Cloudinary and in the example I am rotating it with the "a_120" part on the URL (120 degrees) "https://res.cloudinary.com/defmmlrqg/image/upload/a_120/v1646695548/test/img32_iidhie.jpg"

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52948764/11630806

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the rotation by url with the "a_120" part on the URL. You're image don't really rotate with this method. You need to use [custom overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple). In the exemple in the previous link, to rotate you're image, modify the `draw` method of the custom overlay class by adding something like

```
this.div_.style.transform = 'rotate(120deg)';
```

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948764/google-map-how-to-rotate-groundoverlay-need-trick) for more infos.