# Typescript ReferenceError: google is not defined, but only in standalone files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps

I'm building a React app with an embedded Google Map.

I've got a custom menu element that I want to display on the map after a click. [Google's docs instruct me](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view?hl=en#MapCanvasProjection.fromDivPixelToLatLng) to 'implement' (although I think in Typescript terms, they mean ***extend***) the `google.maps.OverlayView` class in order to render elements over the map.

When I define the `class ContextMenu extends google.maps.OverlayView` class ***inline***, the code compiles fine and my element shows up on click. I want to define this class in a separate file, using Typescript.

However, when I move `ContextMenu` to a separate file, React errors out with `ReferenceError: google is not defined`.

Any idea how to 'import the namespace' such that `ContextMenu.ts` knows where `google` is? It seems like I am missing something fundamental about Typescript here, but none of their documentation I've been able to find has discussed the practice of creating classes with external namespaces.

Or is `extends` the wrong way to do this here? Should I just follow Google's instructions, even in Typescript *which exists to avoid messing with prototypes*?

> Inherit from this class by setting your overlay's prototype: `MyOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView()`;.

---

Working code:

```js
// App.tsx
import React from 'react'
import { Wrapper } from '@googlemaps/react-wrapper'
// cannot define ContextMenu here

const App: React.VFC = () => {
  // cannot define ContextMenu here
  const onClick = (e: google.maps.MapMouseEvent) => {
    // CAN define ContextMenu here
    class ContextMenu extends google.maps.OverlayView {
      private origin_: google.maps.LatLng
      constructor(origin: google.maps.LatLng) {
        super()

        this.origin_ = origin
      }
    }

    const menu =  new ContextMenu(e.latLng)
  }

  return (
    <Wrapper ...>
    // Map goes here
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

---

Broken code:

```js
// App.tsx as above, without ContextMenu defined.

// ContextMenu.ts
class ContextMenu extends google.maps.OverlayView {
  // ...
}
```

---

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40104288/angular2-how-to-setup-a-google-maps-overlayview-translate-js-prototype-into

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to directly extend a google.maps.* class since it actually isn't available (this might depend on tsconfig target, but I haven't tested). You can use the following pattern in TypeScript to delay.

```js
export interface OverlayViewSafe extends google.maps.OverlayView {}

/**
 * Extends an object's prototype by another's.
 *
 * @param type1 The Type to be extended.
 * @param type2 The Type to extend with.
 * @ignore
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
function extend(type1: any, type2: any): void {
  // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
  for (let property in type2.prototype) {
    type1.prototype[property] = type2.prototype[property];
  }
}

/**
 * @ignore
 */
export class OverlayViewSafe {
  constructor() {
    // We use the extend function for google.maps.OverlayView
    // because it might not always be available when the code is defined.
    extend(OverlayViewSafe, google.maps.OverlayView);
  }
}
```

Comment: I saw code like this all over Github when I searched for usages of OverlayView. You have just explained why. Thank you!