# how to use google maps with typescript definitions?

Tags: typescript, google-maps-api-3

if you load the google maps api in the browser [using a `<script>` tag](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) (and not the @google/maps node package), how can you assign typescript types to it? e.g. if I use the [@types/googlemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/googlemaps) package or similar, their types look right, but i don't know how to hook them up to my own `google` variable. seeing some disappointing tsc messages like

> Cannot use namespace 'google' as a type.

[image: confused little frowny man]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Typescript typings for google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064697/how-to-install-typescript-typings-for-google-maps)

Comment: i already answered my question, it's below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ohhhhhhhh! turns out, i wanted `typeof google` e.g.

```
// typescript
var g: typeof google

// js doc
/** @type {typeof google} */
var g
```