# Google places library undefined

Tags: html, angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new to ionic and was trying auto complete search option of google maps api.

After reading so many articles embedded the below code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&v=3.exp&libraries=places‌​&sensor=false"></script>
```

and using the library like

```
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
```

But it is throwing below undefined errors

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'SearchBox' of undefined
>       at MapPage.push../src/app/components/map/map.page.ts.MapPage.initAutocomplete (map.page.ts:173)
>       at MapPage.push../src/app/components/map/map.page.ts.MapPage.ngOnInit (map.page.ts:19)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22098)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23362)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23324)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23958)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23918)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MapPage_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23910)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23306)

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on what exactly you would like to achieve, as well as the code you have got so far, so we can actually help you solve this problem? The details you have given are very little and not enough to answer the question.

Comment: did you replace `API_KEY` with your own API key?

Answer (score 0):

Install Google map types
    npm install --save @types/googlemaps

You can modify your file to include

```
/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />
```

I think there is another way, you can modify tsconfig to add **typeRoots** path. I haven't used this approach.

Reference: [How to install Typescript typings for google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064697/how-to-install-typescript-typings-for-google-maps)