# How to fix type error in Angular Google Maps?

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-places, angular-google-maps

I am using Angular Google Maps in my app, but I cannot use `google.maps.places.PlaceResult` as a type for an important variable in my code.

---

I am implementing this code: (Scroll down to Add Location/Places Search bar)

https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-6-add-google-maps-in-angular-2-plus-applications-using-angular-google-maps-module-agm-core-easily/

I am doing a places search on the map, and I am getting this error:

[image]

In this code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Load places autocomplete
    this.maps.load().then(() => {
      this.setCurrentLocation();
      this.geoCoder = new google.maps.geoCoder;

      let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
        types: ["address"]
      });

      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          // Get the place result
          let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

          // Verify result
          if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
            return;
          }

          // Set latitude, longitude & zoom
          this.userLat = place.geometry.location.lat();
          this.userLng = place.geometry.location.lng();
          this.zoom = 12;
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

I am just following the example, but it seems to not recognize `google`. How do you fix this?

I expect to use the example in the link as it is, but I cannot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064697/how-to-install-typescript-typings-for-google-maps, it seems the google maps package (and @agm which seems to rely on it) are not yet as polished as to easily add their respective types.

Comment: Which root folder do I add `types` to, from the answer you linked me? @JensHabegger

Comment: There's  multiple possible approaches to your problem, I'd try `npm install --save @types/googlemaps` first

Comment: @JensHabegger post your answer from the link you sent me, it fixed my problem. I will give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this issue, you need to add a file called, `google-maps.d.ts` in your root folder inside a folder called `types`.

Then in that file add the following code:

**google-maps.d.ts**

```
import '@types/googlemaps';

declare global {
    interface Window {
        google: typeof google;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to give variables a type in typescript, of type `google.X.X`. Make sure you have types installed into your project, `npm install --save @types/googlemaps`.

Also, make sure you add `types` in your `tsconfig.json` file to point it the folder with the code:

**tsconfig.json**

```
// tsconfig.json
compilerOptions: {
   ...
   "typeRoots": [
     "node_modules/@types",
     "types"
   ],
   ...
}
```

Where I got the answer from, (Scroll down to the second answer by `feilxmosh`):

[How to install Typescript typings for google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064697/how-to-install-typescript-typings-for-google-maps)

Credit goes to @JensHabegger for sending me this link. I answered my own question because JensHabegger did not.