# Cannot find type definition file for 'googlemaps'

Tags: angular-google-maps, angular16

I am using **Angular 16.2.12** for my project. I've installed **@angular/google-maps 16.2.12**. Because **@types/googlemaps** is deprecated so i used **@types/google.maps 3.53.5** then i got following errors:

```
Error: node_modules/@google/markerclustererplus/dist/cluster-icon.d.ts:16:23 - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'googlemaps'.

16 /// <reference types="googlemaps" />
                         ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@google/markerclustererplus/dist/cluster.d.ts:16:23 - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'googlemaps'.

16 /// <reference types="googlemaps" />
                         ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@google/markerclustererplus/dist/markerclusterer.d.ts:16:23 - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'googlemaps'.

16 /// <reference types="googlemaps" />
                         ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@google/markerclustererplus/dist/overlay-view-safe.d.ts:16:23 - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'googlemaps'.

16 /// <reference types="googlemaps" />
```

After searching for a while I tried to install lower version of @types/google.maps, created **declaration.d.ts** in project root and insert **declare module 'googlemaps';** or solution at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064697/how-to-install-typescript-typings-for-google-maps) but the errors still remain. Please help ):