# Cannot read property 'prototype' of null Bing Map

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, bing-maps

I entered the Bing maps in my code using the 'Bing Maps V8 interactive SDK.' My problem is that when I load the Microsoft map of the times and not always, I get an error like:

"Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'prototype' of null"

I do not understand what it is because I followed the suggestions of the "interactive SDK" on the Bing Map Dev Center website.

**ERROR**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of null
at k (mapcontrol?key=key:14)
at n.h [as create] (mapcontrol?key=key:14)
at e (mapcontrol?key=key:14)
at t.l [as instance] (mapcontrol?key=key:14)
at n.h [as create] (mapcontrol?key=key:14)
at e (mapcontrol?key=key:14)
at t.l [as instance] (mapcontrol?key=key:14)
at new Microsoft.Maps.Map (mapcontrol?key=key:16)
at createBingMap (tracking.js:19)
at tracking.js:118
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=YOURKEY"></script>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    (function()
    {
        if(Modernizr.geolocation)
        {           
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
            {
                  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                  var bingResource = ajaxGeoReverse(latitude, longitude);
                  var comune = bingResource[0].toString();
                  var provincia = bingResource[1].toString();

                  createBingMap(latitude, longitude);

                  var positionLocality = {
                    "comune": comune, "provincia": provincia
                  };

                  $.ajax(
                    {
                      type: 'POST',
                      url: 'https://civicsensethecitizen.altervista.org/php/formTrackingTable.php',
                      data: {'items': JSON.stringify(positionLocality)},
                      dataType: 'json',
                      success: function(data) 
                      {
                          $.each(data, function(index, item)
                          {
                              var pushping = createPushpin(map.getCenter(), item.ID, item.Categoria, item.Gravita);
                              map.entities.push(pushping);

                              $('#tracking tbody').append(
                                    '<tr>' + 
                                    '<td id = "segnalazioneID">' + item.ID +
                                    '<td>' + item.Data +
                                    '<td>' + item.Posizione +
                                    '<td>' + item.Categoria +
                                    '<td>' + item.Stato +
                                    '</tr>');
                          });
                      },
                      error: function()
                      {
                        alert('Connsessione non riuscita');
                      }
                    });

            }, failGeo);
        }
    });

    function ajaxGeoReverse(latitude, longitude)
    {
        var bingResource = [];

        $.ajax( 
        {
            url: 'https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/' + latitude + ',' + longitude,
            async: false,
            data: {
              key: 'YOURKEY',
              o: 'json'
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                var result = data.resourceSets[0];

                if (result) 
                {
                    if (result.estimatedTotal > 0) 
                    {
                        var comune = JSON.stringify(result.resources[0].address.locality);
                        var provincia = JSON.stringify(result.resources[0].address.adminDistrict2);

                        bingResource = [comune, provincia];
                    }
                } 
            },
            error: function()
            {
                failGeo();
            }
        });
        return bingResource;
    };

    function createBingMap(latitude, longitude)
    {
        if(typeof Microsoft !== undefined && typeof Microsoft.Maps !== undefined && Microsoft.Maps.Map !== null)
        {
            var navigationBarMode = Microsoft.Maps.NavigationBarMode;

            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('container-gmap'), 
            {});

            map.setView(
            {
                mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial,
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude)
            });

            map.setOptions(
            {
                maxZoom: 15,
                minZoom: 12
            });
        }
        else
        {   
            setTimeout(createBingMap, 500);
        }
    };
```

Comment: You can see your API key in your ERROR, please change your API key.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162044/bingmap-getting-prototype-of-null-error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens. You can also edit out the info and flag your post for a moderator to redact the edit history.

Comment: Ok. I modified the post, forgive me for the incorrect publication of the post. I have already checked that Post but it has not solved my problems and besides I do not use angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue (refer, for example [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68f0079d-7f25-44cc-aea3-c69094bb0094/getting-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-prototype-of-null-after-moving-to-v8?forum=bingmapsajax)) which occurs  while map is  getting initialized but a Bing Maps Control has not been loaded.

At least two solutions are available here:

1) Use `load` event to ensure Bing Maps Control has been loaded, for example:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        initMap(position.coords);
    });
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/BqEXZy)

2) Specify a *callback function* name in the map script  url:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=initMap&key=[YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY]' async defer></script>
```

`initMap` function will be triggered once Bing Maps Control has been loaded

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution is correct and has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a chance that the navigator code will try and add things to the map before the map has fully loaded. This is a timing issue. Consider running your geolocation code after the map has been loaded.