# adding googlemaps to angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, typescript-typings

I am trying to implement googlemaps to my angular-cli project. I know that there is a 'angular2-google-maps' component ([github](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps/blob/master/src/core/directives/google-map.ts)), but I need routes and more custom features.

I found two ways on implementing the map into an project:

1: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931771/how-to-load-google-maps-api-asynchronously-in-angular2): with a google api loader - but I couldn't figure out how to initialise google-maps...

2: with an DefinitelyTyped [google.maps.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/googlemaps/google.maps.d.ts). 
I installed it with --global (since ambient ist deprecated..) into my project and added the index.d.ts (for global) to the src/typings.d.ts and can use "google.map.." in an .ts file:

```
  myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  map:any;

  constructor() {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: this.myLatLng,
      zoom: 4
    });
  }
```

but if I build it with angular-cli it errors: 
"ReferenceError: google is not defined"

any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here a step by step guide to add a google maps component to angular-cli project.

Step1 : install google.maps from DefinitelyTyped:

```
typings i dt~google.maps --global --save
```

Step2 : if you have an older typings installed add

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />
```

to your src/typings.d.ts

Step3 : generate new component

```
ng g component google-maps
```

Add the following code to:

.ts :

```
  height = '100px';
  myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  map:any;

  constructor(private googleApi:GoogleApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.googleApi.initMap().then(() => {

      let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.myLatLng.lat, this.myLatLng.lng);

      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 4
      });

      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: this.map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      });
    });
  }
```

.html :

```
<div id="map" [style.height]="height"></div>
```

Step4 : generate new service

```
ng g service google-maps/shared/google-api
```

Add GoogleApiService + HTTP_PROVIDERS to src/main.ts

code :

```
const API_KEY = '[insert your code]';
const url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='+ API_KEY +'&callback=initMap';

@Injectable()
export class GoogleApiService {
  private loadMap: Promise<any>;

  constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.loadMap = new Promise((resolve) => {
      window['initMap'] = () => {
        resolve();
      };
      this.loadScript()
    });
  }

  public initMap():Promise<any> {
    return this.loadMap;
  }

  private loadScript() {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';

    if (document.body.contains(script)) {
      return;
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }
}
```

Maybe you need to delete some lines from the spec.ts files. 
But then you can add the GoogleMapsComponent as a directive.

- it is super easy to expand with routes etc.
  Maybe if I have time I upload a current version of my GoogleMapsComponent to github..