# Issue: Google maps on Angular CLI not recognized

Tags: google-maps, angular, angular-cli, typescript-typings

I am using angular-cli to build angular 2 app. While using google map object I see following error on build/serve,

> Cannot find name 'google'

I have installed google maps typings(typings version 1.4.0),

```
typings i dt~google.maps --global --save
```

Followed the solutions below which didnt help much,

> [adding googlemaps to angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37807987/adding-googlemaps-to-angular-cli)
>
> [How to install Typescript typings for google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064697/how-to-install-typescript-typings-for-google-maps/36066039)

Please suggest what can I try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue,

> typings > index.d.ts was not updated with google.maps typing reference

After changing that and adding reference to index.d.ts in typings.d.ts it recognizes google map objects.

Comment: can you help me how to add this?