# Why will a google maps API component work without *NgIf but works if excluded? Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps-api-3, angular-ng-if

I tried following the steps laid out in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931771/how-to-load-google-maps-api-asynchronously-in-angular2). It works to load searchboxes with this component:

map.component.html

```
<input id= 'box2'  *ngIf="boxReady" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<input id = 'box' class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
```

map.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {GoogleAPIService} from '../google-api.service';
declare var google: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss'],
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() boxIdVar: string;
  // @Input() id: string;
  boxReady = false;

  constructor(private _google: GoogleAPIService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (typeof google !== 'undefined') {
      console.log(google);
      console.log('Map.NgInit');
      console.log(this.boxIdVar);
      this.boxReady = true;
      let input = document.getElementById('box');
      let originSearch = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
      input = document.getElementById('box2');
      let dest = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    }
    else {
      console.log('Google was undefined Map');
    }
  }
}
```

However, if I add an *NgIf statement that will load one of the boxes only when the component is loaded then that searchbox no longer will work and I get an uncaught promise exception.

map.component.html

```
<input id= 'box2'  *ngIf="boxReady" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<input id = 'box' class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
```

error found in the console:

```
ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: b is null
v$.prototype.o@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/40/5/places_impl.js:78:66
```

This all arose because I wanted to dynamically change the Id of the input box. But it seams that whenever an HTML element has some angular bound variable the functionality breaks.

Comment: I am looking for a variable named 'b' `TypeError: b is null` is there some code missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are querying the DOM in `ngOnInit()`. This is too early in the component lifecycle for Angular to have added it to the DOM. Setting the `*ngIf` condition to true doesn't *immediately* add it to the DOM.

Instead, you should run any code that requires the DOM element later in the component lifecycle, in `ngAfterViewInit()`.

Also, a more "Angular" way to get a DOM element is to use `@ViewChild()`.

```html
<input *ngIf="boxReady" #box2 />
```

```js
@ViewChild('box2') box2: ElementRef;

boxReady = false;

ngOnInit(): void {    
  this.boxReady = true;    

  const viewChild = this.box2 ? this.box2.nativeElement : null;
  console.log('ngOnInit viewChild', viewChild); // null
}

ngAfterViewInit() {  
  const viewChild = this.box2.nativeElement;
  console.log('ngAfterViewInit viewChild', viewChild);
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2um7rp